# TSQL - Controller and Action from URL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, url

My app logs the url requests such as: "/Users/Edit", "/News/" and "/".
Almost all url are also available via web-api, which has a "/api" before everything.

I need a query that

1. given "/Users/Edit/" i get "Users" and "Edit" (optional `/` as long as results are constant)
2. given "/Users/" i get "Users" and `NULL`
3. given "/" I get `NULL` and `NULL`
4. given "/Content/myCss.css" I get "Content" and (`NULL` or "myCss.css")
5. ignores the "/api"

Basically, what i want is to get the controller and the action of that URL text...

Comment: Does it have to be a single query or would several statements suffice? `declare @URL as VarChar(256) = '/api/footloose/fancyfree'; if @URL like '/api%' set @URL = SubString( @URL, 5, Len( @URL ) - 4 ); select @URL; ...`.

Comment: @HABO I would prefer a single one because i will use it on a update statement... i'm preparing another table with specific fields to index and etc and later, extract reports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it done. Try a little xml.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @URLs as Table ( URL VarChar(256), Controller VarChar(256), [Action] VarChar(256) );
insert into @URLs ( URL ) values
  ( '/Users/Edit/' ),
  ( '/Users/' ),
  ( '/' ),
  ( '/Content/myCss.css' ),
  ( '/api/Users/Edit/' ),
  ( '/api/Users/' ),
  ( '/api/' ),
  ( '/api/Content/myCss.css' );
select * from @URLs;

-- Flog it into submission.
select URL, XMLURL, Ele2, Ele3, Ele4, Leonard.Controller, Leonard.[Action]
  from @URLs as U cross apply
    ( select Cast( '<root><ele>' + Replace( URL, '/', '</ele><ele>' ) + '</ele></root>' as XML ) as XMLURL ) as XU cross apply
    ( select XMLURL.value('(/root/ele)[2]', 'varchar(256)') as Ele2,
      XMLURL.value('(/root/ele)[3]', 'varchar(256)') as Ele3,
      XMLURL.value('(/root/ele)[4]', 'varchar(256)') as Ele4 ) as XE cross apply
    ( select NullIf( case when Ele2 = 'api' then Ele3 else Ele2 end, '' ) as Controller,
      NullIf( case when Ele2 = 'api' then Ele4 else Ele3 end, '' ) as [Action] ) as Leonard;

-- Update the table.
update U
  set Controller = Leonard.Controller, [Action] = Leonard.[Action]
    from @URLs as U cross apply
    ( select Cast( '<root><ele>' + Replace( URL, '/', '</ele><ele>' ) + '</ele></root>' as XML ) as XMLURL ) as XU cross apply
    ( select XMLURL.value('(/root/ele)[2]', 'varchar(256)') as Ele2,
      XMLURL.value('(/root/ele)[3]', 'varchar(256)') as Ele3,
      XMLURL.value('(/root/ele)[4]', 'varchar(256)') as Ele4 ) as XE cross apply
    ( select NullIf( case when Ele2 = 'api' then Ele3 else Ele2 end, '' ) as Controller,
      NullIf( case when Ele2 = 'api' then Ele4 else Ele3 end, '' ) as [Action] ) as Leonard;

select * from @URLs;
```

The notion is to convert each URL to XML with each element on the path being a separate XML element. Since the elements can be accessed by index using `XML.value` it is easy to pick out the first few elements, ignore `'api'` using a `case`, and convert any empty strings to nulls using `NullIf`.

---

For those who only understand a dialectic of T-SQL which requires that each line start with a non-numeric, non-alphabetic character, this uppercase translation of the initial example is provided:

```
;DECLARE @URLS TABLE
(URL VARCHAR
(256
)
,CONTROLLER VARCHAR
(256
)
,[ACTION] VARCHAR
(256
)
)
;INSERT @URLS
( URL
) VALUES
('/Users/Edit/'
)
,
('/Users/'
)
,
('/'
)
,
('/Content/myCss.css'
)
,
('/api/Users/Edit/'
)
,
(
'/api/Users/'
)
,
('/api/'
)
,
('/api/Content/myCss.css'
)
;SELECT
* FROM @URLS
;SELECT URL
,XMLURL
,ELE2
,ELE3
,ELE4
,LEONARD
.CONTROLLER
,LEONARD
.
[ACTION]FROM @URLS U CROSS APPLY
(SELECT CAST
('<ROOT><ELE>'
+REPLACE
(URL
,'/'
,'</ELE><ELE>'
)
+'</ELE></ROOT>'AS XML
)XMLURL
)XU CROSS APPLY
(SELECT XMLURL
.value
('(/ROOT/ELE)[2]'
,'VARCHAR(256)'
)ELE2
,XMLURL
.value
('(/ROOT/ELE)[3]'
,'VARCHAR(256)'
)ELE3
,XMLURL
.value
('(/ROOT/ELE)[4]'
,'VARCHAR(256)')ELE4
)XE CROSS APPLY
(SELECT NULLIF
(CASE WHEN ELE2
='API' THEN ELE3 ELSE ELE2 END
,''
)CONTROLLER
,NULLIF
(CASE WHEN ELE2
='API' THEN ELE4 ELSE ELE3 END
,''
)[ACTION]
)LEONARD
;
```

Comment: that is really something you did there. Nicely done, would you mind explaining your thought process for this one?

Comment: One question:
1. How would I use it on a update statement? in my original table i have the column "UrlNoQueryString" which has the URLs and the columns Controller/Action...

Comment: The example has been extended to include an `update` and a bit of explanation tacked on the end of the answer.